# Call item in Subpage from Master | add subpage element into master

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have here a Master->Master2->Subpages.
I now want to add a MultiView to either the Master2 or the Subpages. The content of the Multiview will be defined in the Subpages.

My question is now how:

1.) How do I add a Multiview to the master2 and then add the content from the Subpages to it´s views? So, that I only have to use the Multiview once in the master... I know that I can inject into the master.multiview with innerHTML(), but I would rather not have all those - still changing - sites in a String.

2.) OR, should I add to every Subpage a Multiview (brugh) and the content for that Subpage. But then, how can I define from the Master2, with a  Tabgroup, which View to use? ...or of course I could do that Logic in the Subpages too, but then I have to move quite a lot of duplicated code into the Subpages.

What would be the best way of action?

Comment: Add a `ContentPlaceholder` to each view in the `MultiView`. Then in the page, add a corresponding `Content` which contains the content of each view.

Comment: wow thanks. Didn´t know that it´s possible to have a ContentPlaceholder inside other Elements!